# Json crash when sending space and dot

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, whitespace

I am trying to request a URL and I am getting error saying

> "Data parameter is nil".

I had found that the variables used has got space dot(.). I think this is the problem that is being caused by the URL. So is there any way to send URL having space and dot without crashing?

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.5/mobileapp?/signin=%@&%@",username,password]];

NSError *errors;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSDictionary *json = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&errors];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

```
NSString *myUnencodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"192.168.1.5/mobileapp?/signin=%@&%@",username,password]
NSString *encodedString = [myUnencodedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:encodedString]
```